# QB Desktop to QB Online Migration

Tags: migration, salesforce, quickbooks-online

Que 1. When same trust account is there in desktop and online , When we migrate desktop data then does that create new trust account or it will merge with the existing trust account?

Que 2. When we migrate the deposit does that get link with the existing trust accounts or it creates new trust account for each deposits in Online?

Que 3. how to import Qb Id'd with all the record details in excel

When we migrate desktop data then does that create new trust account or it will merge with the existing trust account.

and rest que just need ans.